# Accepting Friend Request with facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-requests, facebook-friends

It is possible to accept a friend request with facebook API ?

Not the Javascript SDK ones.

Answer (score 2):

Sending and accepting friend requests is not available via the Facebook Graph API for regular user accounts.  You can add and remove friends for test user accounts of your application.  See the [test user documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) for examples if this is what you were referring to.

Comment: Does this change for the 3.5 API?